# Intuitive definition of the Euclidean group without reference to metric

Tags: soft-question, lie-groups, analytic-geometry

Usually, Euclidean space is introduced by giving a three-dimensional vector space ($\mathbb{R}^3$ for simplicity) and the metric
$$d_E\big((x_1,x_2,x_3),(y_1,y_2,y_3)\big)=\sqrt{(x_1-y_1)^2+(x_2-y_2)^2+(x_3-y_3)^2}$$
(or instead the scalar product).

I find this a bit unsatisfying because it's not a priori geometrically obvious that distance can indeed be measured in this way. In other words, the above equation should be a theorem, not a definition.

Instead, we could take the Euclidean group $E(3)$ and define $d_E$ to be the only metric whose isometry group $E(3)$ is (or something similar if that isn't well-defined).

But this only helps if we can somehow define (or axiomatically characterize) $E(3)$ without reference to the Euclidean metric or the Euclidean scalar product, in such a way that it is intuitively clear that it is the group of isometries of space. And by isometries I mean (the intuitive concept of) transformations of space which preserve the shape of rigid bodies.

Defining the orthogonal group via matrices and adding translations or explicitly talking about rotations and reflections does not satisfy this requirement. **So maybe there is a list of "geometrically obvious" properties of the group $E(3)$ and its action on $\mathbb{R}^3$ that uniquely characterize $E(3)$.** Or something similar for $O(3)$.

Of course, this is not a 100% precise question, but I hope someone has thought a bit further in this direction and can give an overview of relevant results or guide me to the literature.

Comment: There are [several proofs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem#Rearrangement_proof) of the pythagorean theorem that don't need to define metrics. It can also be proved for arbitrary norms so in this case it's not a definition but a trivial corollary. In fact, the euclidean metric comes after the pythagorean theorem (historically and in the sense that it is inspired by it), so it shouldn't make you feel akward to get the theorem so easily with that definition.

Comment: @Javi: The mention of Pythagoras' theorem was misleading, I've replaced it with what I actually wanted to say.

Comment: One can find, buried rather deeply in the 20th century literature of Euclidean geometry, an axiomatic treatement of the Euclidean plane which incorporates, from very early in the axiomatic scheme, a treatment of the group of rigid motions of the plane. Is that the kind of thing you had in mind?

Comment: @LeeMosher: Yes, but such a treatment probably spends a lot of time on getting from points and lines to $\mathbb{R}^2$. The treatment I had in mind would start with $\mathbb{R}^3$ and a group $G$ of bijections of $\mathbb{R}^3$ onto itself, state a few axioms about $G$, and eventually define the metric, scalar product, etc in terms of $G$.

Comment: Well, this still begs a lot. I might wonder what structure on $\mathbb R^3$ you would accept as being "given". By writing "a group $G$ of bijections of $\mathbb R^3$ to itself", it almost looks like you are not willing to accept a topology, let alone a smooth structure. That being the case, you would really just be starting with a group $G$ of bijections of a set of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$, and as you say such a treatment probably spends a lot of time getting from there to your desired endpoint.

Comment: @LeeMosher: I would accept a topological vector space structure, which seems reasonable because there is only one. I wrote "group of bijections" in order not to exclude the possibility of getting continuity through some other axiom.